# /etc/crypttab not updating in initramfs

Tags: ubuntu, luks, zfs, initramfs, crypttab

I have a new installation of ubuntu 22.04, with full disk encryption (LUKS) and ZFS picked from the ubuntu installer options.

I need to make some edits to `/etc/crypttab` so that unlocking my drives works in an automatic way (fancy usb auto unlock), but the edits I'm making to `/etc/crypttab` aren't persisting to initramfs.

What I'm doing is:

- Editing `/etc/crypttab`
- Running `update-initramfs -u`
- Rebooting my machine into the the system that asks for the LUKS password (initramfs)
- Checking the contents of `/etc/` but crypptab isn't there.

Have I got my concept of how this works incorrect? I need to persist some version of crypttab to the loader but it isn't working.

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm here because I ran into the same problem, found this question via Google, and have some information to add. I am attempting to auto-unlock a LUKS drive without having type a passphrase.

First, I edited `/etc/crypttab` and changed its entry to the following:

```
sda3_crypt UUID=2d661ff8-d6a8-49c9-ae96-4d6e234bffe2 /dev/zero luks,discard,keyfile-size=32
```

Then, I added a new key using the following command:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey --new-keyfile-size 32 /dev/sda3 /dev/zero
```

Finally, I ran `update-initramfs` which produced the following output:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-2-amd64
cryptsetup: WARNING: sda3_crypt: key file /dev/zero has insecure ownership, see 
    /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.Debian.gz.
cryptsetup: WARNING: Skipping root target sda3_crypt: uses a key file
```

This already seemed suspicious, but I rebooted anyway. Unfortunately, these actions made the system unbootable:

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
Gave up waiting for root file system device: Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/legend--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!


BusyBox v1.35.0 (Debian 1: 1.135.0-2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) cat /etc/crypttab
cat: can't open '/etc/crypttab': No such file or directory
```

I was able to successfully boot the system again by entering the following commands at the BusyBox prompt:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file /dev/zero --keyfile-size 32 /dev/sda3 sda3_crypt
exit
```

The original question still stands though: why is `/etc/crypttab` not available in the initramfs?

### Update

After more research, I can now finally answer the original question: `/etc/crypttab` is not present in initramfs because [the default unlock](https://sources.debian.org/src/cryptsetup/2%3A2.5.0-6/debian/initramfs/cryptroot-unlock/) script does not use that location; it uses `/cryptroot/crypttab` instead.

To make `/etc/crypttab` available as `/cryptroot/crypttab` in initramfs, create the following script in the `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks` directory and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /etc/crypttab "${DESTDIR}/cryptroot/crypttab"
exit 0
```

Finally, let it be noted that using auto-unlocking LUKS devices by using empty passphrases defeats the purpose of encryption. It is just as insecure as using no encryption at all.

Comment: this is amazing, i thought this question would go nowhere - i'm going to try this on my machine and if it works i'll thumbs-up you the answer.

Comment: Thanks ! The script works great on my Debian bookworm !

Comment: Note that /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot is supposed to have the magic to create the /cryptroot/crypttab file.  The above example of /dev/zero might work, but a more realistics example using a different keyfile would require additional care and feeding to install the keyfile into the correct location (which conceptually the listed hook is supposed to do)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running `sudo update-initramfs -u`, run `sudo update-initramfs -c -k -all`

I ran into this problem after adding a new nvme drive, encrypting.

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Ubuntu 22.04) all went as expected when I ran the following commands after having edited the /etc/crypttab:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart cryptsetup.target
```

I.e. after having added a line in the crypttab I can now see:

- the new decrypted device in /dev/mapper/
- the changes are persisted also after the reboot

Comment: This only works if your root partition is not the one you are trying to decrypt---this process does not do the `update-initramfs`.  However, it will allow you to decrypt partitions other than root.  Note that the daemon-reload causes the crypttab to be re-read, otherwise the cryptsetup.target will ignore your change.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which this discussion helped me fix, but without the need to add a hook, as suggested above.

My encrypted partition is on sda3, but because I copied data from a prior configuration with a different partition scheme, my /etc/crypttab looked like this:

> sda6_crypt UUID={uuid] none luks,discard

It appears that when the initramfs image is generated (as when a new kernel is installed, but also on other updates), a mismatch between the naming in /etc/crypttab and the actual partition causes an error (which of course I didn't see) such that the file in the initramfs (located at /cryptroot/crypttab) was empty (zero bytes).  This lack of a file is what causes the boot process to hang.  Correcting /etc/crypttab to:

> sda3_crypt UUID={uuid} none luks,discard

solves the problem.  Of course, if your initramfs is already honked it needs to be regenerated:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

But future updates should proceed normally.

Answer (score 0):

For me (since I have been burned before) I did a double-check.  (This was ubuntu 20.04, but the answer is relevant to 22.04 as well)

After `update-initramfs -c -k all` I did a `mkdir /tmp/x; cd /tmp/x; unmkinitramfs -v /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) .` and inspected `/tmp/x/main/cryptroot/crypttab`.  It was empty.

The solution for me was to edit `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook` and create a keyfile pattern.  My final configuration was:
`KEYFILE_PATTERN=/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/*.key` in conf-hook, and `myroot UUID="8481c1f8-91d4-469d-9132-12d3948f503a" /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/root.key luks,discard` in /etc/crypttab.  The key, *without an end of line newline* was of course in `/etc/cryptsetuyp-keys.d/root.key`

After doing so, an unpacking the initramfs, I saw a `main/cryptroot/crypttab` that looked sane, and the keyfile (with a new filename) was copied into `main/cryptroot/keyfiles/myroot.key` ("myroot" matches whatever was in the initramfs's crypttab.